# Write common method - Java

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
public static List<KeyValueDTO> valuesList() {
    return Arrays.stream(Kitchen.values()).map(e -> {
        KeyValueDTO k = new KeyValueDTO();
        k.setKey(e.name());
        k.setValue(e.getValue());
        return k;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static List<KeyValueDTO> valuesList() {
    return Arrays.stream(KeyLocation.values()).map(e -> {
        KeyValueDTO k = new KeyValueDTO();
        k.setKey(e.name());
        k.setValue(e.getValue());
        return k;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I want to write a common method that can call for the above two methods. How can I write that common method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume `Kitchen` and `KeyLocation` are enums, in which case they already share a common `name()` method. For `getValue()`, one solution is to have them implement a common interface:

```
interface Valuable {
    String getValue();
}
```

Now you just pass in an array (of `E`, representing some subtype of `Enum` and `Valuable`) and let the method do the rest:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E> & Valuable> List<KeyValueDTO> valuesList(E[] values) {
    return Arrays.stream(values).map(e -> {
        KeyValueDTO k = new KeyValueDTO();
        k.setKey(e.name());
        k.setValue(e.getValue());
        return k;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

If that's not possible, you can pass in a function to extract the value:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> List<KeyValueDTO> valuesList(
        E[] values, Function<E, String> getValue) {
    return Arrays.stream(values).map(e -> {
        KeyValueDTO k = new KeyValueDTO();
        k.setKey(e.name());
        k.setValue(getValue.apply(e));
        return k;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Which can be called like this:

```
List<Kitchen> values = valuesList(Kitchen.values(), Kitchen::getValue);
```